# Mockito and Eclipse rcp

Tags: java, eclipse, mockito

I am trying to use mockito on my eclipse rcp project. For some reason I get this error each time I am going to run my unit-test:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mockito/Mockito Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mockito.Mockito

My code is similar with this in mockito sample:

```
@Test
public void testExecuteStep(){
  List test = mock(List.class); //here the exception will be thrown.
}
```

Can anybody give me a solution of this problem?

Comment: Don't you have a classpath problem ?

Comment: I don't think so. I can build my project the problem is at runtime.

Comment: It could be the runtime test classpath, that have some issues. Also you said you were developping an eclipse RCP project, does it mean you are actually developping a plugin or something alike? If yes, I know Eclipse works on top of an OSGI "container", it could mean something is not configured properly on this side, yet I'm not sure as I don't much about OSGI.

Comment: @Brice yes I am working on rcp plugin. I will try to check this staff with osgi. Thank you.

Comment: Oh, lol, struggling at this problem just now. We're using a Tycho-maven build, and tests is running fine from it, but from eclipse JUnit runner is'f failing with NoClassDefFoundError.

Comment: @execc let me know if you find any solution of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me that Mockito is not properly setup in your project, are you sure that it's on the **classpath**?

Comment: The solution was to add it to the run Test settings classpath.

Comment: I had the same problem, but found out that I had to have compatible versions of mockito and powermock as I was using the two together.